# Python Thread not running

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

Following a simple threading tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_Z1lgZLSNc&ab_channel=NeuralNine) but thread not starting? simple asks for user input and ends, no output or counter or anything. Calling the function without threading works fine and outputs counter.

```
import threading
import time

done = False

def worker():
    counter = 0
    while not done:
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)

threading.Thread(target=worker).start()

input("Enter to quit")
done = True
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the above code, I got:

```
Enter to quit1
2
3
4
5

6
```

This seems to be the correct behavior for code but correct me if I am wrong.

Perhaps, you clicked enter before the first output of the worker thread or one of your package imports is faulty. Please post more details if the issue persists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i've discovered that it works when run directly from command line, it just doesn't work in IDLE Shell.
Many thanks